# Max file size for Magento custom option uploads?

Tags: php, magento

I've looked everywhere on Google but I cannot see if there's a way to do this - I have custom options on my Magento products which allow the customer to upload a file. But I need to put a filesize limit on this to stop someone sending me a 99GB file which brings down the server.

There must surely be somewhere I can set this?

Comment: I should mention I'm using Magento 1.4.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to php setting `upload_max_filesize`. You can change this from *php.ini* and other variables affected are `post_max_size` (the amount of data that can be posted via forms) and also everything sent must fit to memory/disk

[see more from php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Comment: Ah ok, I've seen that this can also be overridden in .htaccess too: http://www.maheshchari.com/increase-php-file-upload-limit/

Thanks to whoever voted my question down btw. I should apologise for asking an honest question.

Comment: read the FAQ of the site then you'll understand the down-vote :(

Comment: Read the FAQ, still don't understand the problem. There are plenty of Magento questions asked here, I was simply asking if there was a setting in Magento (code or admin) that allowed me to control a certain aspect of its functionality. I got my answer, now anyone else with a similar problem who's unsure will have the answer too. Good grief!

Comment: Sure, if you filter by tag Magento then you notice that 90% of "how to do it via admin" are down-voted also and also lot of 1 point wonderers questions as well. It really is a common sense question for any web-dev who is doing something with php (rtfm type of question) or in server side. I guess google would have revealed this answer with first result and i notice that the attitude "search until you drop and then ask" is preferred approach here

Comment: Tbh, it sounds more like arrogance to me. What may seem common sense to some people may not be to less experienced developers - I thought people here would prefer it if users have searched for the answer themselves before asking...

Comment: An old question but totally fits my current scenario, I need to set the limit of uploaded file sizes without relying on the configuration in PHP.  As pointed out in the answer, can be done by code. I upvoted this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the max size attribute via `.htaccess`, this is true. But you could be more fine-grained inside Magento via a callback function with `Varien_File_Uploader` for a given interface. So you could set the size of an application to have a post value `50MB` as a maximum site wide with a `.htaccess` file but restrict the file limits on certain interfaces further, `10MB` for A `20MB` for B, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Reusing the field *image_size_y* in the table *catalog_product_option*, we can set the max file size here. Then, we need to overwrite 2 core files and 2 *phtml* files.
1. Overwrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option`

```
protected function _afterLoad()
{
    $this->setMaxFileSize();
    return parent::_afterLoad();
}

public function setMaxFileSize()
{
    if (!preg_match('/(jpg|png|bmp)/i', $this->getFileExtension())) {
        $this->setData('max_file_size', $this->getImageSizeY());
        $this->setData('image_size_y', 0);
    } else {
        $this->setData('max_file_size', 0);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

2. Overwrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Type_File`

```
public function setOption($option)
{
    $option->setMaxFileSize();
    $this->_option = $option;
    return $this;
}

protected function _getUploadMaxFilesize()
{
    if ($kb = $this->getOption()->getMaxFileSize()) {
        return min(parent::_getUploadMaxFilesize(), $kb*1024);
    }
    return parent::_getUploadMaxFilesize();
}

protected function _bytesToMbytes($bytes)
{
    return round($bytes / (1024 * 1024), 2);
}
```

3. \app\design\frontend\yourpackage\default\template\catalog\product\view\options\type\file.phtml:

```
<?php $_option = $this->getOption()->setMaxFileSize(); // replace first line of code ?>
...
<!-- add the following after <?php if ($_option->getImageSizeY() > 0): ?>...<?php endif; ?> -->
<?php if ($_option->getMaxFileSize() > 0): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('options_<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>_file').addClassName('validate-file-size');
    $('options_<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>_file').setAttribute('max-file-size', <?php echo $_option->getMaxFileSize() ?>);
    </script>
    <p class="no-margin"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Maximum file size')?>: <strong><?php echo $_option->getMaxFileSize() ?> <?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('KB')?></strong></p> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

4.\app\design\frontend\yourpackage\default\template\catalog\product\view\options.phtml, add the following js:

```
Validation.add('validate-file-size', '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Exceeded maximum file size'))?>',
    function(value, elm) {
        var maxsize = +elm.getAttribute('max-file-size') || 1024; // kb            
        var size = elm.files[0].size/1024; // kb
        return maxsize > size;
    }
);
```

The above tested in Magento 1.9.0.1 on Firefox, the validation script may not work in IE.